# Order mysql search results by # of times words occur

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok, I have a large set of data in my table which is as follows (its actually larger)

```
 userid year  model  color  transmission  interiorcolor wheels
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   2008  Fiesta   Red       MT         Black        Stock
   2   2008  Monaro   Red       AT         Black        Stock
   3   2005  F-150S   Blue      AT         Black + Red  Stock
   4   2008  Fiesta   Green     MT         Black        Stock
```

Now, there is a search box which allows users to input any keywords they want, be it the year, model, color, transmission, etc.

Right now my search can find all results which hit on any keyword the user enters, but it's not very relevant as Mysql will sort based on hits alone.

I need to have the search results sorted by the # of words in the search query that hit on items.

For example if someone types in "2008 Fiesta", he should get record #1 and #4 in his results before #2 --- because records #1 and #4 contain two of his keywords vs. record #2 which only contains one of his keywords.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at fulltext searches.

Comment: Or indexing/search engine like sphinx, apache lucine... Though at start you wont need that i guess :)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2010/08/17/how-sphinx-relevance-ranking-works/) alongside MySQL for relevance ranking.